# Sending a mobilepush message to specific device in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

We have a use case to send the Push message to the latest device of the customer. Is there a way via journey builder that we can leverage to send the push message to the specific/latest device .

There is an API :     POST /push/v1/messageContact/{messageId}/send  but this seems to specific to message and to leverage via Mobile Push module.

Appreciate a reference or a options we can explore.